# Logback load configuration priorities

Tags: java, logging, logback, configuration-files

Official documentation [describes](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration) priorities for classpath configuration (`test -> groovy -> xml -> Configurator SPI`) and [mention](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#configFileProperty) the system property named `logback.configurationFile` to specify external configuration. But what if the product contains the logback.xml on the classpath and user specify external config with `logback.configurationFile` property. Which config will be loaded classpath or external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for version 1.2.3 (latest stable version), the property has the highest priority. The configuration loaded in the [`ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/branch_1.2.x/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/ContextInitializer.java) class in `findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile` method

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full list from higher to lower priority:

1. `logback.configurationFile` system property (only `*.xml` and `*.groovy` are accepted)
2. `logback-test.xml` from the classpath
3. `logback.groovy` from the classpath
4. `logback.xml` from the classpath
5. [`Configurator`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/Configurator.html) implementation specified by `META-INF/services/ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator`
6. Default `BasicConfigurator` (console appender)

Source: [logback `ContextInitializer` v.1.2.6](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/v_1.2.6/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/util/ContextInitializer.java).